# How can i update data on Calender using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Currently i am using `[fullCalendar][1]` javascript library.

I has a two type's parameter(A,B).

A parameter is "A group" money datas, B parameter is "B group" money datas

if `document` changed. i am request parameter and response data.

How can update my Calender datas?

Here  my javascript code :

```
var type = '';  
$(document).on('change','#calendar-menu',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var calandar = $('#calandar');
        if(e.target.value == 'details'){
            type = e.target.value;
             $.ajax({
                url: '/sales/calendar2/details?type='+type,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(xhr) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                }
            }).always(function() {
                loading_hide();
            });
        }else{
            $.ajax({
               url: '/sales/calendar2/details?type'+type,
               dataType: 'JSON',
               type: 'POST',
               success: function(doc) {
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
               }
           }).always(function() {
               loading_hide();
           });
        }
        console.log(e.target.value);
    });
```

Comment: Do you have the running code uploaded somewhere to see the demo ?

Comment: @kiran-krishnan here my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whz7ahq6/) !

Comment: You can use a drop down and pass it's value to your json feed with jQuery ajax data option, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35418300/5360631 that is using checkboxes

Comment: @smcd thanks fixed !